# java.io.IOException: Stream closed accessing config files outside of jar folders

Tags: java, linux

I'm executing a jar file which reads configs from a config file outside of **/home/user/xxx/testFolder/jarfile**, the path of config file is **/opt/xxx/conf/global_config.cfg.**

However, I'm able to access files inside the jar, so I assume the error is due to the file not being found.

Below is my code:

```
public Properties createProperties(){
    Properties p = null;
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    try (InputStream stream = cl.getResourceAsStream("/opt/xxx/conf/global_config.cfg")) {
        p = new Properties();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        p.load(bis); // this is throwing the error
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p;
}
```

What is the correct way of getting a file regardless of its path in a Linux system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cl.getResourceAsStream("/opt/xxx/conf/global_config.cfg")
```

expects the resource to be available in relation to the class location. So, it will search as a relative path to the class inside the JAR. But the path `/opt/xxx/conf/global_config.cfg` is a absolute disk path, and for reading it , you need to use the `FileInputStream`

```
public Properties createProperties(){
    Properties p = null;
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    try (InputStream stream =new FileInputStream("/opt/xxx/conf/global_config.cfg")) {
        p = new Properties();
        p.load(stream);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p;
}
```